# How to reference a jar (containing only stubs) created with rmic:package maven goal from a POM?

Tags: java, maven-2, rmi

I have a RMI app and the Stubs are generated with maven (rmic:rmic).

Then I use the rmic:package goal and get a nice little jar with only the stubs.

Now the bis question is: How can I reference this jar from the poms of other projects?

I cant give it an ArtifactId (or do I?!) and when I use the classifier, it downloads all dependecies of the original Project and NOT the jar with the stubs.

Please give me a hint, how I can actually use this jar in a nice behaving maven way :-)

thanks in advance, I vote for stuff and accept answers, so you'll get your points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could indeed create a project/POM for your Stub Project.

You could bind the `rmic:rmic` goal to the `generate-sources` phase of a "Stub Project" POM; so that the compile phase of the build 1) creates the stub classes and then 2) compiles them.

This would then allow you to `package` the project (as a JAR, or whatever else) and `deploy` it to a Maven repository like any other project.

From there, you would simply reference the artifact as a `<dependency>` of the projects that depend on the stubs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a classifier of `client`.

Example:

```
<!-- This references the stub jar -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>the-dependency</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <classifier>client</classifier>
</dependency>

<!-- This references the jar -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>the-dependency</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```